# Declare a constant in a Typescript Class

Tags: typescript, class, static, constants

What is is the best way to declare a constant in a TypeScript `class`?

Comment: you can use const . refer (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)

Comment: Thank you @AmiLinn for the answer and the the link, the problem is that I was hesitating between a readonly and const

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare a constant, you can declare a `readonly` field, which is weaker then what you would expect from a constant but might be good enough:

```
class MyClass {
    static readonly staticReadOnly = 10;
    readonly instanceReadonly = 10;
}

console.log(MyClass.staticReadOnly);
console.log((new MyClass).instanceReadonly);
```

I say it's weaker because at runtime the value can be changed, and more over even within the type system we can violate `readonly` without a type assertion:

```
let mutable: { instanceReadonly: number } = new MyClass() // valid assignment
mutable.instanceReadonly = 11; // we just changed a readonly field
```

If you can I would stick with a regular `const` declaration outside the class.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Titian that's the explanation that I was looking for :)